# How to get drawStrings on new lines

Tags: java, graphics, newline, drawstring

So, I have this `String`(snippet below) which has a fair amount of information

```
highscoreString += (i + 1) + ".\t\n" + scores.get(i).getName() + "\t\t\n" + scores.get(i).getScore() + "\n";
```

which is inside this method

```
public String getHighscoreString() {
    String highscoreString = "";
    int max = 10;

    ArrayList<Score> scores;
    scores = getScores();

    int i = 0;
    int x = scores.size();
    if (x > max) {
        x = max;
    }
    while (i < x ) {
        highscoreString += (i + 1) + ".\t\n" + scores.get(i).getName() + "\t\t\n" + scores.get(i).getScore() + "\n";
        i++;
    }
    return highscoreString;
}
```

And what I am trying to do, is put that information in a `g.drawString();` which I can do easily, but what I cannot do is, to go onto a new line once it gets to the end of that `highscoreString`(first snippet shown).

This is what I've done so far using the `g.drawString()` method

```
g.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 10));
        g.drawString("" + hsm.getHighscoreString(), 40, 310);
```

Even if I put `\n` at the end of the `highscoreString`, it wont end the line...

I'm aware of the fact that I can use this method to make new lines

```
void drawString(Graphics g, String text, int x, int y) {
for (String line : text.split("\n"))
    g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
}
```

But, how would I be able to split the `highscoreString?`

Comment: For my money, I'd try to display my String in a JTextArea, one set with `setLineWrap(true)` and `setWrapStyleWord(true)` methods both called and set to true. I know that I can get rid of the text area's background so that it doesn't even look like a JTextArea if I wanted to.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ah, I think I'm aware of what you mean. But I already have a JFrame with a functioning game, and I want this ranking system to be in the main menu, so I could put a JTextArea inside of it and remove the background(of the JTextArea)?

Comment: `"...I want this ranking system to be in the main menu, so I could put a JTextArea inside of it and remove the background(of the JTextArea)?"` -- I cannot say for sure since I'm not sure what your main menu is comprised of. I assume that it's some type of Swing component since you're drawing in it, and since most all Swing components can act as containers and thus can accept a JTextArea, I will assume that it's possible. As usual though, the devil will lie in the details of your current code and problem.